# Mobile Authenticator using CTAP2 specifications

Tags: authentication, mobile, fido-u2f, webauthn, fido

I am looking for the use case/scenario for setting up a smart phone as an authenticator using CTAP2 specifications.

I am looking for the use case in which a user setup the browser to interact with their smart phone the same way it would when using Yubikey or another similar security key. I have read all the documentations related to it but unfortunately what I always get an article using Yubikeys / other USB devices as the authenticator. I am looking forward for some interaction where mobile phone serves a  roaming authenticator.

By having a look at the documentation and CTAP specification conceptually I know this can be done by having some connection between the phone and the host via:

- Bluetooth
- NFC
- USB

After establishment of connection the mobile authenticator could then implement the CTAP2 protocol so that the browser considers it as roaming authenticator. I am also looking forward to see  the authentication process using some BLE enabled device. I have already tried log-in using yubikey security key on  website. But I want  to achieve the same flow login-mechanism using Bluetooth enable Thetis BLE key  or mobile itself.

Any insights would be very helpful. I am also looking forward for people working on this particular use case to have a mutual discussion.

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to follow this [spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-id-20180227/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-id-20180227.html) to develop your roaming authenticator. FIDO2 standard is recommended if you start the development now. There are 2 modules which may take your time to research & develop your authenticator: BLE, FIDO Crypto logic. This is the hardest work because there is no kind open source published for reference, you must be totally working with [spec](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-id-20180227/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-id-20180227.html).

Second, you can use one these clients to test your authenticator while developing:

- https://webauthn.io
- https://demo.yubico.com/webauthn-technical/registration
- ...

Note: It's not convenient to do iOS authenticator now. Please check this [issue](https://groups.google.com/a/fidoalliance.org/forum/#!topic/fido-dev/xDriNjLzcIg) to see why

Third, you may use [FIDO Conformance Tools](https://fidoalliance.org/test-tool-access-request/) to validate your authenticator.

Finally, you may go get certified and register on [MDS](https://fidoalliance.org/metadata/metadata-service-terms/) if need

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for the same thing. For future readers as of now 2020, below resources are helpful if anyone else is looking.

You could look into https://github.com/solokeys/solo which provides open source implementation for hardware and firmware. It is a great starting point. As they have ctap implemented they also have hid emulation using usb_gadget for linux.

You could also look into https://github.com/github/SoftU2F which is a software u2f for MacOS using mac keychain.